System.AggregateException in worker .NET 8 project
I am trying to implement a windows service by using worker project with communication to a SQL Server database.
ON running it, I am getting two exceptions :

System.AggregateException:  Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TTRWindowWorkerService.TTRService.TTRReportService: Cannot consume scoped service TTRWindowWorkerService.TTRRepository.ITTRReportRepository from singleton Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService.


InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service TTRWindowWorkerService.TTRRepository.ITTRReportRepository from singleton Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService.

This is my Program.cs:
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder() .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

 IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) .ConfigureServices(services => {  
                    services.AddDbContext<SMPdbContext>(opt => { 
                        opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
                      }); 
                       services.AddScoped<ITTRReportRepository,TTRReportRepository>();
                       services.AddHostedService<TTRReportService>();
                 })
         .UseWindowsService()
         .Build();

  await host.RunAsync();

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone explain it to me? I didn't find any solution for it.
I tried to make a windows service by using background services of Worker project. There I call a dbContext from a library project and try to insert the data into a table in very minute by using LINQ but my project is not even starting its giving me exception. I tried to use singleton but it  is also now working.
My service constructor:
public class TTRReportService : BackgroundService
{
      private readonly ITTRReportRepository ttrRepository;

      public TTRReportService(ITTRReportRepository _ttrRepository)
      {
          ttrRepository = _ttrRepository;
      }
}

Repository file:
public  class TTRReportRepository(SWMdbContext _dbContext) :ITTRReportRepository
{
       public void UserStatusUpdate()
       {
           var count = _dbContext.Countries.Count();

           Country county = new Country
           {
               CountryName = $"test{count}",
               IsActive = true        
           };

           _dbContext.Countries.Add(county);

           _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       }
}


This is known issue. Have you tried to make your repository Singleton. services.AddSingleton<ITTRReportRepository,TTRReportRepository>();
I really like to see your Worker service constructor.

I tried but It dint worked.

Error is saying it correctly.

Background service is singleton so it can not access scoped service.

You have to do something like this.
public class TTRReportService : BackgroundService
{
      private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

      public TTRReportService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
      {
          this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
      }

      protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
      {
               // Here you might be calling or using repository.
             using(var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
             {
                var repository = scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<ITTRReportRepository>();
                // Now use this repository. 
             }
      }
}


I'll tried but still the same issue

Instead of calling repository I just make a scope by using ScopeFactory in service and than call the dbContext there which fix my exception
 private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public TTRReportService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }



   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                    {
                    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SWMdbContext>();
    }   
  }
}


I have suggested same thing.  If your repository is scoped and dbcontext tends to be scoped so it solve the problem.
